# arcpy CompositeBands for each folder, name new raster by folder

Tags: arcpy, python, remote-sensing

I am processing multibands remote sensing rasters (i.e. Sentinel data). Each set of bands is stored in individual folder. I would like to list folders and list rasters (bands) in each folder to create a raster composite. Each new raster I would like to store under the folder name. How can I name the new raster by folder name?

```
# create raster composite per folder

import arcpy
import os

# 
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/clipy/"  
outws = "C:/Users/output"

# list folders
folders = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 

for folder in folders:
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*.tif")
    name = os.path.join(outws, folder[1])
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management(rasters, name)

print "Raster composite complete"
```

I'm using ArcGIS 10.4 and python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Bjorn's answer, you need to specify the output raster name properly using something like the following:

```
raster_name = os.path.join(outws, folder.split("\\")[-1] + '.tif')
```

This strips the folder name from the path generated from `ListWorkspaces()`, which can then be used to create an output path and file name (including a file extension).

---

```
import arcpy, os

inws = r'C:\path\to\indata\directory'
outws = r'C:\path\to\outdata\directory'

arcpy.env.workspace = inws
folders = arcpy.ListWorkspaces()

for folder in folders:
    raster_name = os.path.join(outws, folder.split("\\")[-1] + '.tif')
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder
    rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()
    arcpy.CompositeBands_management(";".join(rasters), raster_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`rasters` contains a list of the raster files in the workspace. CompositeBands needs that list converted to a semicolon-delimited string. Change the CompositeBands command to `arcpy.CompositeBands_management(";".join(rasters), name)`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run your code and realized that I would like to name new composite raster by the folder name. I updated my question. Please, some more help?

Comment: After looking at help, I realized that I misunderstood what you were doing. This should make more sense.